# Bind jQuery click event to regular javascript button

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to create a simple function in jquery to direct the user's browser to the previous page if the Cancel button is clicked but I'm a bit mythed as to how to do it since I have minimal experience of jquery.

```js
<input type="button" id="cancelBc2" name="cancelForm" value="Cancel">
$(document.ready(function() {
    $('cancelBc2').click(function() {
        var cancel = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave the page?");
        if (cancel == true) {
            window.location = "chooseConfig.php";
        }
    });
});
```

Am I missing something or is the page just completely overlooking the

```
$(document.ready(function()?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the # on the selector

```
$('cancelBc2')  //looking for an element <cancelBc2 />
$('#cancelBc2')  //looking for an element with id="cancelBc2"
```

And you have a typo

```
$(document.ready
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

even better

```
$(function(){});
```

Comment: Than you have another problem.

Comment: Wow... Missed that typo there... Thank you for spotting that for me!

Answer (score 3):

Should add prefix # to select Id in jQuery

```
$('#cancelBc2').click(function() {
    var cancel = confirm("Are you sure you want to leave the page?");
    if (cancel == true) {
        window.location = "chooseConfig.php";
    }
```

});

For information: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, but you are missing the proper selector. It should be `$('#cancelBc2')`

This selects the element in the DOM with the id `cancelBc2`

For a full list of jQuery selectors utilize this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: That is what I tried at first but still no luck. I am using the $(document.ready(function() somewhere else on a previous page. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: Yes. Look at the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/shrimpboyho/AFbEL/1/ That is how document ready should be.